# Website doesn't search for .php extension

Tags: php, web

I have a new site and when I try to click any link to a page such as /home.php it takes me to /home/ and says file does not exist instead of just going to home.php.

I currently have the following code in htaccess, but what else should I add?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [r=301,L]
```

Comment: Index button, is this a `<button>index</button>`? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You did not specify a directory index in your server/host settings. I assume you're using Apache, so you've got to set the `DirectoryIndex` directive to `index.php` - if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: What web server software are you using and what OS? Apache on Windows/Linux? IIS on Windows?

Comment: When I load a page by clicking a button it searches for the /file/ instead of the /file.php.  this is good source code so I doubt there's a problem with it.  this leads to file not found

Comment: Should be on http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to be a little more specific in order to help solve this issue.  What type of project is this?  Is it built around any sort of PHP framework?

You might be able to solve this issue using your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: I currently have the following in htaccess

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [r=301,L]

Comment: @user This looks strange. Have you tried to remove it ?